# How can I programmatically display/show the DatePicker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: datepicker, xamarin.forms

I created a Xamarin.Forms cross platform App that uses webview to display content from local HTML files named With dates.
I added toolbar items:   'previousDay', 'NextDay',  and 'Goto Date'.
Every other thing is working except 'Goto Date' item

I created a DatePicker so that user can select the date to load the HTML file for the date.
The DatePicker didn't display/open.

How can I programmatically display/show the DatePicker when 'Goto Date' Tollbar Item is clicked.

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker()
{
Format = "D",
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
MinimumDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),
MaximumDate = new DateTime(2017, 12, 31),
};
```

dp.Focus();

Please, help!

Comment: you need to add it to your view stack - right now you've created it but it's not part of your page's layout

Answer (score 1):

Jason is right.
You have to add all controls to your view stack to be able to use it.
If you - like you wrote - show your data in a webview, you e.g. can add a stacklayout as main control and then add the datepicker as first and the webview as second control.
The page then shows the datepicker on top and below the webview. 
Your further can show and hide the controls, if you want (e.g. show the datepicker only, if a button / toolbar item is tapped.
If you add the datepicker already to your viwe stack, you have to show us your code (in this case something in your code seems to be wrong).